# Memory usage of large transactions

Tags: postgresql, memory, transaction

I have an application which persists itself to a PostgreSQL 11 server. It does this by truncating the tables (removing the old state) and then uploading its current state (many statements) as part of one transaction - So, if something goes wrong the old state will be preserved. It's difficult to calculate a delta, which seemed like a sensible compromise

I've recently noticed occasional `SIGKILLs` wiping out the DB after my application runs for a long time (the information to save grows), with the `Failed process running:` being this persistence cycle. I'm wondering if this is due to the single mega transaction being a large blob in memory which eventually `OOMs`, and if so would breaking it up into subtransactions/savepoints address the problem? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Large transactions aren't usually a problem, unless you have deferred constraints or are using the new statement level triggers and their "virtual" tables

Comment: You should disable memory overcommit.